# JavaScript Function Activation Issues

Tags: javascript, android, html, button, visibility

I have another question that's been bugging my mind since I started using js fairly recently so that my app would be nicely responsive but I've been hit with another block here.

As the title says I am having serious issues with a particular code.
Here is its summarized form

```js
window.onload = onLoadFunctions;

function onLoadFunctions(){
  var show3rdDiv = document.getElementById('show3rdDiv');
  var editbtnStart = document.getElementById('editbtnDiv');
  var editbtnLog = 0;
  
  editbtnStart.style.display = 'none';
  
  show3rdDiv.onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById('3rdDiv')className = "";
   if (editbtnLog == 1) {
  editbtnStart.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
  editbtnStart.style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
  }

function submitclick(){
  var uname = document.getElementById("login").elements[0].value;
  var upass = document.getElementById("login").elements[1].value;
  var preuname = "john";
  var preupass = "doe";
if (preuname == uname && preupass == upass) {
  editbtnLog = 1;
  document.getElementById('2ndDiv')className = "";
  alert("The user " + preuname + " was successfully loged in and editbtnLog wass set to: " + editbtnLog);
  }
  else {
    alert("Wrong Username or password!");
   }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="login">
  <form id="login">
  Username<input type"text" placeholder="name">
  Passowrd<input type"password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitclick()">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="2ndDiv" class="hidden">
  <input type="button" id="show3rdDiv" value="Continue">
</div>
<div id="3rdDiv" class="hidden">
<div id="editbtnDiv">
        <input type="button" id="editbtn" value="Edit"/>
</div>
</div>
```

No matter what I do that `editbtn` won't appear or disappear the way an object that requires something should do. And if you noticed i used it's div instead? that's coz it would never appear at all if i just used the input button itself.

Someone please tell me how this is wrong is so many ways?

I tried a lot of styles and I don't really want to use the `onclick=""` (refer to that Submit button that I hate so much) on my html coz people say it's bad to use it. What should I do here? It got annoying like yesterday already.
Am i missing something? Did I declare this wrong? The furry mermaids i'm loosing precious eyebrow hairs on this project already. <=[
Or maybe i should just stick to the `onclick=""` thing when it comes to showing that edit btn?

Answer (score 0):

The "id" attribute is the only

```js
window.onload = onLoadFunctions;

function onLoadFunctions(){
  var show3rdDiv = document.getElementById('show3rdDiv');
  var editbtnStart = document.getElementById('editbtnDiv');
  var editbtnLog = 0;
  
  editbtnStart.style.display = 'none';
  
  show3rdDiv.onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById('3rdDiv').className = "";//error
   if (editbtnLog == 1) {
  editbtnStart.style.display = 'block';
  }else {
  editbtnStart.style.display = 'none';
  }
  }
  }

    function submitclick(){
      var uname = document.getElementById("login").elements[0].value;
      var upass = document.getElementById("login").elements[1].value;
      var preuname = "john";
      var preupass = "doe";
    if (preuname == uname && preupass == upass) {
      editbtnLog = 1;
      document.getElementById('2ndDiv').className = "";//error
      alert("The user " + preuname + " was successfully loged in and editbtnLog wass set to: " + editbtnLog);
      }
      else {
        alert("Wrong Username or password!");
       }
    }
```

```html
<div id="login1">
      <form id="login">
      Username<input type="text" placeholder="name">
      Passowrd<input type="password" placeholder="password">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitclick()">
      </form> 
</div>
    <div id="2ndDiv" class="hidden">
      <input type="button" id="show3rdDiv" value="Continue">
    </div>
    <div id="3rdDiv" class="hidden">
    <div id="editbtnDiv">
            <input type="button" id="editbtn" value="Edit"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i don't get you... at all :/

Answer (score 0):

Please Check weather your Script is calling properly or not.Check the line where you define the script.

Comment: i checked it a dozen times but i already figured it out somehow :/

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minutes ago... (note: this is embarrassing!) i figured it out.
(This is not shown in the summarized codes mentioned above)
I made an element that changes its html value like a login button that turns into a logout if you are successfully logged in and changes back if you click it in its logout form so there is a loop. The button's value changes so i experimented a bit and realized that i could tie them together somehow. So i did. By declaring an `onclick=""` to the `show3rdDiv` button and a starting class of `class="hidden"` to `editbtnDiv` and stating that if the login button has a value of "login" then it keeps the hidden class but if it has a value of logout then it deletes that class.
I'm so stupid sometimes. :/